# Exposing multiple implementations of a interface as OSGI service

Tags: spring, osgi

I have an interface that has two implementations. I want to expose both implementations as OSGi services, but when I am doing that one overrides the other. Please find the configuration that I am doing:

```
<bean id="formService" class="com.dbt.form.service.FormService"/>
<bean id="formAPIService" class="com.dbt.form.service.FormAPIService"/>
<osgi:service 
    ref="formAPIService" 
    interface="com.dbt.form.service.ifc.IFormService"/>
<osgi:service 
    ref="formService" 
    interface="com.dbt.form.service.ifc.IFormService" />
```

Here `formService` is overriden by `formAPIService` implementation.

Please help me on how to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 8):

The second service does NOT override the first... both of these services will be published separately, and you can confirm this by typing the `inpect cap service` command in the OSGi Gogo shell.

What MAY happen is that your consumer code will only choose one of the available service instances. In this case you need to write your consumer to either bind to all instances, or use a combinations of rankings or target filters to determine which particular service you want. You should give more information on how you are using these services since that is where the problem lies (probably).

Answer (score 3):

Read this page...[Chapter 8. The Service Registry](http://static.springsource.org/osgi/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html/service-registry.html) section 8.2.2.3.

You can use **bean-name** attribute of osgi **reference** tag. While importing a service *bean-name* refers to the *id* attribute of that service when its exported.